# cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, android-studio

Buen día!!
Tengo un error en código en la cual antes no me lo marcaba.
Este es mi error:

```
Error:(1012, 9) error: constructor Crop in class Crop cannot be applied to given types;
required: Uri,Uri
found: Uri
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Este es el metodo que me marca el error en **new Crop**.

```
 private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
        // Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(registerActivity.getCacheDir(),
        // "cropped"));
        Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), (Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg")));
        new Crop(source).output(outputUri).asSquare().start(activity);
    }
```

Ojala me den una idea de como solucionarlo. Gracis.

Comment: que libreria estás usando para el Crop ?, puedes poner tu build.gradle file

Comment: que tal!! es esta android-crop https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, al parecer estabas usando una versión desactualizada, según veo la documentación, la forma de llamar al crop es la siguiente:

```
Crop.of(inputUri, outputUri).asSquare().start(activity)
```

En tu caso quedaría así :

```
Crop.of(source,outputUri).asSquare().start(activity);
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! te lo agradezco mucho.